# How to implement a searchable TreeField?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-storm, treefield

I got how to implement a [TreeField](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6022/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/TreeField.html). But how to implement a searchable [TreeField](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6022/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/TreeField.html)?

Comment: means suppose i ve 4 elements in TreeField.
Then when I type a character in TextField it will search in the TreeField. In JDE samples I got "KeywordFilterDemo" for searchable List. So how to implement the same for TreeField ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say to implement something like [List with checkbox along with search criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163456/list-with-checkbox-along-with-search-criteria/1163515#1163515)

So you have vector of TreeField controls, each has some text value, on enter text you walk through all vector and on first equality focus a field.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply to add a editField and a treefield and add a  changeListener to the editField. When it changes (write a char) you repopulate the treefield... that is the easiest way. I assume you have the date where you populate the treefield previously, so now must to select only those who meets the criteria..